# JavaScript scope basics: listening to custom events?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, backbone.js

A question about JavaScript scope. I have three files (I'm using Backbone, though I'm not sure if that's relevant). The first file defines a Google Maps custom infowindow. The second file defines a Google Maps marker and applies the infowindow to it. And finally, the third file adds markers and other page elements to the map.

I would like the third file to be able to listen for mouseover events on the infowindow, and call methods on other page elements when they occur. However, my JavaScript isn't good enough to know how:

```
// InfoWindow.js defines the info window & adds a mouseover event
AI.InfoWindow.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView;
AI.InfoWindow.prototype.onAdd = function() {
  this.listeners = [
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.$content.get(0), "mouseover", function (e) {
       clearTimeout( window.hidePopupTimeoutId );
    }) ...
  ];
};

// Marker.js defines the map marker and adds the infowindow 
AI.Marker = function() {
  google.maps.Marker.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
  this.infoWindow = new AI.InfoWindow();
}

// Home.js creates the markers for the map
var myOtherHomePageElement = new AI.OtherHomePageElement();
var marker = new AI.Marker({
   data: entity 
});
// how to listen to infowindow events here?
```

So my question is this: the mouseover on infowindow is working fine, but I want to be able to call `myOtherPageElement.start()` whenever there is a mouseover. How can I do this from within the Home.js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Backbone.trigger` and `Backbone.on` to notify the object in Home.js when the mouseover happens.

```
// InfoWindow.js defines the info window & adds a mouseover event
AI.InfoWindow.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView;
AI.InfoWindow.prototype.onAdd = function() {
  this.listeners = [
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.$content.get(0), "mouseover", function (e) {
       clearTimeout( window.hidePopupTimeoutId );
       Backbone.trigger('infowindow:mouseover', e);
    }) ...
  ];
};

// Marker.js defines the map marker and adds the infowindow 
AI.Marker = function() {
  google.maps.Marker.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
  this.infoWindow = new AI.InfoWindow();
}

// Home.js creates the markers for the map
var myOtherHomePageElement = new AI.OtherHomePageElement();
var marker = new AI.Marker({
   data: entity 
});
Backbone.on('infowindow:mouseover', myOtherHomePageElement.start, myOtherHomePageElement);
```